# Correct Wordpress + Nginx + php-fpm Configuration

Tags: nginx

I have a website running on nginx + php-fpm and I'm looking for a config file that actually shows me a 404 and some other error pages, because the current state of my config file only changes the URL and doesn't show me a 404 page. For example.

I go to `mywebsite.com/some-non-existent/url` and I'm greeted with the homepage instead of the 404 page.

Also, is the `try_files` syntax "safe" to use or should I use rewrites?

I've read the nginx documentation extensively and the wordpress codex config too.

Below I'l paste my Config file to see if someone can shed some light on the subject.

```
server {
       listen 127.0.0.1:80; 
    server_name my.website.com;
    root home/my.website.com;

    access_log logs/my.website.com-access.log;
    error_log logs/my.website.com-error.log notice;

    charset utf-8;
    index index.php;
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args&$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
         deny all; 
    }

       error_page   404             /index.php?error=404;
}
```

And also fastcgi_params included above

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Also, does nginx read location from top to bottom? if so, when it hits `fastcgi_pass` does it read/execute  the configuration below it or goes directly to php?

Edit: X-posted from WP StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always prefer `try_files` to rewrites.

The only real issues I see with your configuration are:

```
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

For WordPress it's not necessary to pass in the `$args`; it gets them from the environment instead. My working configuration has:

```
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Second, you have a stray `/` here:

```
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

This *might not* be a problem, but for sanity's sake I wouldn't leave it.

```
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Hmm I've heard that try_files are better than rewrites, but how does WP gets the info from the environment?
I've made the changes accordingly just to be safe. Also, do you have any answer for the last part of my question? cheers

Comment: Seconding the question about how WP gets the info from the environment, because the example in [the nginx wiki on Wordpress](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress#Non-root_try_files_to_URL_redirect) does add `$args`.

Comment: It reads REQUEST_URI on webservers which pass it (which is everything except IIS). On IIS, it reads a variety of other variables which may be passed in.